# Memcache not being cleared on cache flush

Tags: 6, caching

When clearing the cache, either through /admin_menu/flush-cache or `drush cc all`, the cache isn't cleared, without errors. I've tried doing it directly through telnet, on memcache, getting "OK" as result, but old pages are still being presented to users.

I am using the Memcache module 1.10; in the settings.php file, I added the following.

```
$conf['cache_inc'] ='sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
  '127.0.0.1:11211' => 'sessions',
  '127.0.0.1:11212' => 'cache',
);
$conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
  'cache' => 'cache',
  'cache_form' => 'database',
);
```

Although the session bin is configured, it's not in use. I also have http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/05/21/memcachephp-stats-like-apcphp/ set up, tried using the "Flush this server" option, and get OK as result.

Comment: There are at least 2 modules that allows Drupal to use memcache. Please tell us how exactly your install looks like, how do you test this and how do you clear manually.

Comment: Have added some extra information. We've been running memcache for a week now and some changes are appearing on pages but I've recently made a CSS change. Clear cache through *admin/settings/performance* doesn't seem to have any affect.

There was another issue but that seems to be caused by a huge menu not updating properly as opposed to memcache.

Comment: Try manually by: `echo 'flush_all' | nc localhost 11211`

Comment: same issue I am facing old content is showing after refreshing the page new content show. I am using drupal 8 and memcache . Can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't a memcache problem but a LESS preprocessor issue.

Comment: if you're having CSS & JavaScript issues, I would look into using [advagg](https://drupal.org/project/advagg)